# Execute my Autofill Javascript on Chrome extension click

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a working Javascript which prompts the user for his email and password for first time; and afterwards, it autofills the username and password whenever the user revisits that webpage. In my html code, I just have to call my checkCookie() function to perform this on JSFiddle.net.

Now I want to create a Chrome extension which on click runs the autofill JS. I have these codes but on extension click, I get no output. Can anybody suggest me what am I doing wrong.

```
 // manifest.json

{
   "manifest_version": 2,

   "name": "Auto-fill Passwords",
   "description": "This extension autofill password on click.",
   "version": "1.0",    
   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

   "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}




// background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) 
{ //Fired when User Clicks ICON

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        "file": "autofill.js"
    }, function () { 

  function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);

            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;

        }

function checkCookie() {
var username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
var n= getCookie("username",username);
if(n)
{
  alert("UserID Match! The user's password is " +n) ;
}
else
{
  //alert("UserID  password doesnot exist ");
  var password = prompt("Please enter your password:", "");
                username += "!";
        username += password;
alert("Username = "+ username);
setCookie("username", username, 365);

}

}


        console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
    });
 }
});


//autofill.js
alert("Check cookie function is called");
checkCookie();
```

Comment: I was earlier employing the use of content-script but I read somewhere it is better to use background.js for this task. Looking towards some nice suggestions. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have too much brackets in your `background.js`. And I would also recommend to declare `setCookie()` and `checkCookie()` functions inside autofill.js (if you want to call it inside the injected script). Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to execute autofill.js script with `checkCookie()` inside before you actually declare those functions in callback function. You also didn't specify required permissions in the manifest file. I changed your code a little bit. Now it works. However, you didn't specify `getCookie()` function, so you may wish to do it and use the part of code I left commented.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Auto-fill Passwords",
  "description": "This extension autofill password on click.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],    
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    "file": "autofill.js"
  }, function() {

    alert();

  });

  console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
});
```

autofill.js:

```
alert("Check cookie function is called");

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);

  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;

}

function checkCookie() {
  var username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
/*
  var n= getCookie("username",username);

if(n) {
    alert("UserID Match! The user's password is " +n) ;
  } else {

  //alert("UserID  password doesnot exist ");
  var password = prompt("Please enter your password:", "");
  username += "!";
  username += password;
  alert("Username = "+ username);
  setCookie("username", username, 365);
*/
}

checkCookie();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will surely try this on weekend, and will let you know. Thanks for answering

Comment: It's been over 10 years now, did it work?