# textbox input value not changing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome-extension

The following code changes the 'text' of the field but it is not picked up by the website. When you submit the form, it says the field is still empty and to enter a valid number.

```
var number = 123;
var field = document.getElementById('textfield');

field.value = number;
```

The code above only visually changes the textbox's input. Is there a way to imitate a physical field entry (to have it picked up by the form)?

The type changes from text when its not selected to number when selected.

Comment: sounds like the code excepts onchange to fire, but setting the value does not trigger change

Comment: If the form is expecting a number, why are we converting the number to a string?

Comment: @Dr.Tenma it does not work with either string or num

Comment: @epascarello so would that be ```field.onchange()```?

Comment: We need to know what your submit function is doing.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma the following js code is supposed to work on a website and automatically fill in that field when script is executed (script just sends a number to be entered in the field)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I still haven't seen your submit function so I included one as an example below.

Is this what you are expecting?

```js
var number = 123;
var field = document.getElementById('td-wb-order-price-amount-limit-price');
var example = document.getElementById('example');


function clickMe() {
field.value = number.toString();;
example.innerHTML = "Your input value is " + number;
}
```

```html
<input _ngcontent-axt-c487="" name="limitPrice" type="text" tdwbinput="" tdwbnumberinput="n4-2" 
required="" nonzero="" min="0" maxlength="7" tdwbnumberinputgroupseparator="true" 
class="td-wb-order-price-amount__input-limit-price td-wb-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" 
id="td-wb-order-price-amount-limit-price" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">

<button onclick="clickMe();">Click </button>

<p id="example"></p>
```

Comment: I added the input field's HTML code to the question if that helps

Comment: I've updated my snippet. Is that closer to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you own the website where you are trying to populate these fields? - Or do you have backend access to this website?

Comment: Yes, my example above demonstrates what this functionality would look like. - If you don't own, manage, or have access to the website where you are trying to populate fields then you cannot target the elements on someone else's page to manipulate them. If this was true then the entire internet would be in a very interesting situation :)

Comment: Then how do autofill extensions work if there is no way to do it?

Comment: Which extension are you referring to? It's likely that they either have access to the website or they are using an API.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill-for-chrome-by-fi/ojhegjfmbbpahdggoekcbmejnifimeca?hl=en here is an example and there is many more

Comment: You may be able to do something like that using cookies, I found this post with something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613061/execute-my-autofill-javascript-on-chrome-extension-click - There are also a few other posts that show the functionality you desire but it's nothing I'm familiar with. Seems like you're on the right track though.

Comment: I'll look into it because after looking at the field attributes I noticed there was no 'value' attribute so that might be why its not working

Answer (score 0):

You will need `onchange` attribute to detect the change in the input field.

```js
const handleChange = () => {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
  console.log(inputValue)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onchange="handleChange()" />
```

Comment: This is not my code, this is a website's code so I can't add any new attributes. I am working on an extension and need to fill that field using javascript.